# Single line increment and return statement in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, increment

Having been playing around with C# the last few days and trying to take advantage of its "succinct" syntax I have tried to use the following trick.

```
Int32 _LastIndex = -1; 
T[] _Array;
_Array[_LastIndex++] = obj;
```

Now the problem with this is that it returns the value prior to incrementing the number, so I tried...

```
_Array[(_LastIndex++)] = obj;
```

And yet the same behavior is occurring (Which has also got me a bit confused).

Could someone firstly explain why the second example (I understand why the first) doesn't work? And is there some way of accomplishing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surrounding the post-increment `_LastIndex++` with parentheses doesn't separate it into a distinct operation, it just changes:

```
_Array[_LastIndex++] = obj;    // _Array[_LastIndex] = obj; _LastIndex++;
```

into:

```
_Array[(_LastIndex++)] = obj;  // _Array[(_LastIndex)] = obj; _LastIndex++;
```

If you want to increment before use, you need the pre-increment variant, as follows:

```
_Array[++_LastIndex] = obj;    // ++_LastIndex; _Array[_LastIndex] = obj;
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `_Array[++_LastIndex]`.

`LastIndex++` increments the value but returns the old value.

`++LastIndex` increments and returns the incremented value.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
_Array[++_LastIndex] = obj;
```

This is called pre-increment, which means the increment takes place before the value is used.  Parentheses are used to modify precedence, not necessarily change the order of evaluation.  Further, the parentheses had no effect on the precedence in this instance.